# Returning the URL's as a list from a YouTube search query

Tags: python, search, youtube, youtube-api

How would one create a list containing the URL's of the videos from a normal YouTube text search?

Comment: Also have you looked at the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#search_by_keyword ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I wrote you a quick script to do this. Replace `textToSearch` with your query. It pulls the results from the first page of YouTube results using `urllib`, and prints all the links of the videos by parsing the page using `BeautifulSoup`. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

textToSearch = 'hello world'
query = urllib.parse.quote(textToSearch)
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
    print('https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href'])
```

this gives the output:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al2DFQEZl4M
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRKqlw0DaDI
...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sQEQkMDBjw
```

Comment: great script. One addition, I'd recommend adding: `if not vid['href'].startswith("https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/"):` after the `for vid ...`

Comment: urllib2 also have quote function. and you can directly pass response to BeautifulSoup

Comment: That script was very useful to me! I am using it to 'http stream' with vlc. The script gives the first 20 results. Do you know how can get more than 20? Thank you!

Comment: Not working for me in 2022